# Which is the correct term - an Actionscript or a Flex library?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flex4

This is targeted at developers who consider themselves Flex or Actionscript developers.

I'm writing a helper library to aid connecting to an API from a Flex application.

If you were looking for said library; would you be searching for:

- "Flex {API name} client library" or
- "Actionscript {API name} client library"

Or would you search for both?

Thanks!

Comment: I would search for ActionScript.

Comment: If your client library can be used outside Flex SDK project, e.g within Flash IDE, then I would prefer "Actionscript {API name} client library", otherwise go with "Flex {API name} client library"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a client library written in ActionScript for use in any environment that supports ActionScript, compatibility with Flex is a given but that in no way makes it a 'Flex' library.

It is an ActionScript library and I would assume that a Flex programmer looking for connectivity to your API would make the connection.

If you want to promote discoverability, you could note in the verbage the various use cases for the library, e.g. ActionScript Library Foo for use in Flash/Flex/XXXX.

Answer (score 2):

If it's Flex specific I'd say Flex. If not; Actionscript.

Flex is stricly a "subset" of Actionscript. If it works in pure Actionscript, it'll work in Flex too. I see no reason to call it a Flex library unless it's dependent on or only useful in relation to just that.

Comment: Flex is not a subset of ActionScript, so -1 for that. The Flex Framework has everything that ActionScript has, plus some, so you might call it a superset.  But, realistically, The Flex Framework is just a library of ActionScript classes, along with a method for creating UI components.  Flex, however, is less specific and refers to more than just the framework, it also includes the Flex Compiler, debugger, and other tools for building apps on the Flash Platform.

Comment: +1. I agree with your reasoning. Or anyway it's what makes more sense to me (although www.Flextras.com has a point about "superset" vs "subset").

Comment: I am very much aware of what Flex is and I'd argue that the Flex or Flex Framework discussion is a bit irrelevant here. No one's considering calling it a Flex Framework Library.

Answer (score 1):

Unquestionably I would be searching for a "Flex client library" or "Flex component".  I would only look for an "Actionscript" library if it had nothing to with Flex.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for both. I'd expect the flex api to make use of the mx namespace, and the actionscript api to be vanilla actionscript. (So if you are using the mx namespace, don't call it an actionscript library).

Comment: you know that Flex 4 is split up into three different namespaces, right?  mx, s, and fx.  It is perfectly valid to create Flex libraries that have no dependencies to the mx library.

Answer (score 0):

I would name it "Actionscript {API name} client library for Flex" since it's written in ActionScript (I'm assuming), targeted for Flex development.